# Cannot import WebKit in python via gi.repository on Mac High Sierra

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, webkit, pygobject

I have been trying to prepare a development where I can use GTK and WebKit in python for the past few days. I have given up on ubuntu and now I just want to focus on mac first. I have installed the pygobject3 and I can load the GTK 3.0. But I can't get the WebKit working. The error message is this,

```
>>> import gi
>>> from gi.repository import WebKit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 888, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/importer.py", line 127, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name WebKit, introspection typelib not found
```

I have tried with "WebKit2", "WebKit3" etc...

I have also downloaded and build the WebKit from [webkit.org](https://webkit.org/running-webkit/),and it did nothing.

I would love to have some guidance over all to properly install it, I can upload any test you wish me to run and promptly update it here.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

The following is the current way of importing WebKit:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')

from gi.repository import WebKit2
```

The required Debian/Ubuntu packages are: `python3-gi gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37`

Here is an example that renders Google starting page:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(800, 600)
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
webview = WebKit2.WebView()
webview.load_uri("https://google.com")
scrolled_window.add(webview)

window.add(scrolled_window)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Finally, the PyGObject API Reference can be found [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/).

Comment: It would be nice to explain the "-1" votes

Comment: I guess it is due to the fact, that you answered with an (probably working) ubuntu solution to a Mac OS question

Comment: Ok. But the given python code is not related to an OS.